# Make a repeated component with dynamic content in WordPress

Tags: design

How can I repeat my own CSS design **component** with dynamic content in WordPress?

I have a custom PSD template which I have to migrate to WordPress. I wonder how to make a custom component.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE.  CSS selectors work the same on a WordPress site as they do in any HTML.  A set of CSS properties will be applied to any element/class/ID selector combination that matches.

Comment: You may want to look into WordPress "blocks". These are much like the HTML version of the components you describe. Then you'd style the blocks with CSS in your site's theme. See https://winningwp.com/wordpress-blocks/ for an overview.